# how can i solve system.invalidcastexception error in c#

Tags: c#, phpmyadmin

when i am running my code i am getting an invalidcastexception error at line 8 in ** quote

```
MySqlCommand cmd = Conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select type, sum(bottles) as 'total' from creamtable group by type";

MySqlDataReader ResultSet = cmd.ExecuteReader();

List<Cream> totalcream = new List<Cream> { };

while (ResultSet.Read())
{
    string type = ResultSet["type"].ToString();
    **int bottles = (int)ResultSet["total"];**

    Cream c = new Cream();
    c.type = type;
    c.bottles = bottles;
    totalcream.Add(c);
}
```

Comment: You can solve it by using a debugger to check what type `ResultSet["total"]` is and adjust your code accordingly. If you get that exception it's not somthing that can be directly cast to an `int`.

Comment: What is the SQL data type of "total"?

Comment: `int bottles = Convert.ToInt32(ResultSet["total"]);`

Comment: Did you try [`GetInt32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datareaderextensions.getint32?view=net-6.0#System_Data_DataReaderExtensions_GetInt32_System_Data_Common_DbDataReader_System_String_)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `ResultSet["total"]` returns `object`, which is *reference type*. If actual value is of *value type* (`int`, `long`, `double` etc.) it will be *boxed*. In case of boxing a simple cast is *restricted*:

```
   byte b = 123;
   object o = b; // boxing
   int i = (int) o; // run time error, only (byte) cast is OK

   int k = (int) b;            // OK (no boxing) 
   int j = Convert.ToInt32(o); // OK (Convert)
```

In your case, it can well be that `ResultSet["total"]` is boxed `long` or `double` value. In this case you can try `Convert`

```
   int bottles = Convert.ToInt32(ResultSet["total"]);
```